# Execute command in a new window

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, gnome-terminal, wayland

I'm trying to curl weather in a new terminal window, with the size of the terminal that shows full report.

I've figured out how to do both things but i can't figure out how to do it in one window as the command bellow first curls weather in the existing and then opens a new empty window.

```
alias wttr="gnome-terminal --geometry=136x43 && curl -4 https://wttr.in/MyCity"
```

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-terminal` can be given a command to run as arguments:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=136x43 -- curl -4 https://wttr.in/MyCity
```

However that will run `curl` and close immediately; to see the results, run a shell instead and have it wait for <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry=136x43 -- sh -c "curl -4 https://wttr.in/MyCity; read"
```

As an alias:

```
alias wttr='gnome-terminal --geometry=136x43 -- sh -c "curl -4 https://wttr.in/MyCity; read"'
```

Comment: Ah, I see.. - Thanks! This works from the terminal but as an alias gives an error since the second part is in quotes. How can i format the command so that it executes properly?

Edit: Figured it out. Thanks once again Stephen - Much appreciated! 

```alias wttr="gnome-terminal --geometry=136x43 -- sh -c 'curl -4 https://wttr.in/Lukavac; read'"```

Comment: @Jack_Sparrow if this answer solved your issue please accept it with the tick mark. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers